Probability with Permutations and Combinations
Consider the following problem. Consider a random arrangement of the letters in $GOOSE$. What is the probability the arrangement is $OSGOE$. Now, we know, that the probability is the number of favourable outcomes over the total number of outcomes. If we consider the number of arrangements of $GOOSE$, we get $\frac{5!}{2!}=60$. Hence the probability should be $\frac{1}{60}$. However if approach this differently, we get a probability of $\frac{2}{5!}=\frac{1}{60}$. It seems, whether we treat the $OO$ as distinct $O$, or whether we treat the $OO$ as a repeat, the the result is the same. However, sometimes this isn't the case. How do we know which one to use?
Generally, do we use permutations, when calculating probabilities, as even though two cases may appear the same, both can occur probabilistically, and we shouldn't divide by repeats?
Eg. Consider arranging 3 red flower and 6 yellow flowers in a row. Find the probability that the 3 red roses are not separated. Here, does it matter whether we treat the flowers as distinct, or whether we treat the red flowers all the same, and all the yellows all the same. Do both produce the same answers?
Find the probability that no two red roses are next to each other. Which one do I use here? Whether I should treat the objects as distinct or the same is confusing me.

We get the same answer. If red flowers are indistinguishable and yellow flowers are indistinguishable, then there are $7$ positions for the unseparated group of three red flowers. And there are $\binom 93$ ways to choose positions for red flowers in the row, overall. So the probability is $$\frac7{\binom93}=\frac{7\cdot6}{9\cdot8\cdot7}=\frac1{12}.$$
If we consider the flowers different, then overall there are $9!$ permutations. There are $7$ possible positions for the leftmost red flower, $3!$ ways to arrange red flowers, and $6!$ ways to arrange yellow flowers. Hence the probability is $$\frac{7\cdot3!\cdot6!}{9!}=\frac7{\;\frac{9!}{3!\cdot6!}\;}= \frac7{\binom93},$$ as in the previous case.
If you start to treat the objects as distinct while calculating, it can’t change the answer in problems of this kind. Notice how the first calculation is just the second one in disguise. Calculating $\binom93$ is done by making flowers distinct temporarily anyway.

The key is to count favoured outcomes (ways to spell $OSGOE$) and total outcomes (ways to rearrange the word) in the same manner.
If you treat the $O$ as distinct characters, there are $2$ favoured outcomes among $5!$.
If you treat the $O$ as indistinguishable, there is $1$ favoured outcome among $5!/2!$.
Obviously this will lead to the same answer: $1/60$.

You can only do this problem if you specify how the sampling is to be done. Unfortunately, while elementary statistics courses often do discuss this issue carefully, many elementary probability courses gloss over it, relying on students to catch on to the assumptions made by problem setters. I will discuss two ways of doing the sampling in your problem and in a number of variants. This should help you see what kind of thought process is needed to answer your question more generally.
There are at least two natural ways of doing the sampling in your problem, which happen to give the same answer.

From the set of words that can be spelled with a G, an S, an E, and two Os, select a word uniformly at random, that is, with equal probability.
From the set of linear arrangements of letter tiles containing the letters G, O, O, S, and E, select an arrangement uniformly at random.

The question is, what is the probability the selected word is OSGOE / the selected arrangement spells OSGOE?
The reason these give the same answer is that for every outcome in (1) there are exactly two outcomes in (2), and this holds, both for the sample space as a whole, and for the event in question.
Now consider a variant of the problem where you use four of the five letters. Here are two possible sampling procedures:

From the set of four letter words that can be spelled using at most one G, at most one S, at most one E, and at most two Os, select a word uniformly at random.
From the set of linear arrangements of four tiles taken from a set of five letter tiles containing the letters G, O, O, S, and E, select an arrangement uniformly at random.

Similar question: what is the probability the selected word is OSGO / the selected arrangement spells OSGO?
Again the answers are the same. For the first procedure there are $3\cdot12=36$ words containing two Os and $4!=24$ words containing one O. Since all words are assumed equally probable, the probability is $\frac{1}{60}$. For the second procedure there are $2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1$ ways to lay out tiles that spell OSGO and $5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2$ ways altogether to arrange the tiles (which are all equally probable). Again, the probabilty is $\frac{1}{60}$.
How about three letter words, still with the same five letters? What's the probability say, of arriving at the word OOG? Now we get different answers for the two different sampling procedures. For procedure (1) there are $3\cdot3+3\cdot6+3!=33$ words. (The terms correspond to words with two, one, or zero Os.) So any particular word like OOG has probability $\frac{1}{33}$. For the second procedure, OOG may be obtained in $2\cdot1\cdot1$ ways, out of $5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways to pick and arrange three letter tiles. So the probability is $\frac{1}{30}$. Why the difference? In the second method, not all words are equally likely anymore. The $27$ words with one or two Os are twice as likely as the six words with no O.
The reason the two procedures give the same answer for the five and four letter versions, but not the three letter version, is that in the five and four letter version all words contain an O. If letters are chosen and placed from left to right, the leftmost O (which might be the only O) is twice as likely as the other letters. As soon as you can have words without an O, you will start to have words that don't get this doubled probability, so that words are not all equally likely anymore. You can think about how these issues play out in more complicated situations. You could start with the word REDEEM and then on to COCOON.
By the way, for both of your flower problems you may treat the flowers as distinct (as real-world flowers, of course, are), or you may choose to ignore the distinction. Ignoring the distinction includes considering the $3!$ ways of permuting the red flowers as the same, which means dividing all counts of arrangements by $3!$. Likewise it includes considering the $6!$ ways of permuting the yellow flowers as the same, which means dividing all counts of arrangements by $6!$. So all counts of arrangements will get divided by $3!\,6!$. Since this division affects numerator and denominator equally, it does not affect the result

To get rid of your doubt on whether the two "$O$"s are distinct or not, just use the conditional probability method instead of counting as follows:
$$\underbrace{\frac{2}{5}}_{O} × \underbrace{\frac{1}{4}}_{S}× \underbrace{\frac{1}{3}}_{G}×\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}}_{O}×\underbrace{\frac{1}{1}}_{E}=\frac{1}{60}.$$
Using the same method you can find the probability that the 3 red roses appear first not separated, i.e., $$RRRYYYYYY$$ when arranging 3 red flowers and 6 yellow flowers in a row as follows:
$$\underbrace{\frac{3}{9}}_{R} × \underbrace{\frac{2}{8}}_{R}× \underbrace{\frac{1}{7}}_{R}×\underbrace{\frac{6}{6}}_{Y}×\cdots×\underbrace{\frac{1}{1}}_{Y}=\frac{1}{84}.$$
Similarly, the probability that the 3 red roses not separated is
$$7× \frac{1}{84}=\frac{1}{12}$$
where $7$ is the number of ways that the block $RRR$ appear among 9 flowers, i.e., $$RRRYYYYYY,\\ YRRRYYYYY,\\ \vdots\\YYYYYYRRR.$$

You can see that from the conditional probability method (in which the distinction of the objects is not important) we obtain the same results as when we assume the objects of the same type (the two $O$s or three $R$s) are distinct and use the counting method as follows:
$$\frac{2 × 1 ×1 ×1 ×1 }{5!}=\frac{1}{60}$$
$$\frac{3 × 2 ×1 ×6× \dots ×1 }{9!}=\frac{1}{84}$$
$$\frac{7 × (3 × 2 ×1 ×6× \dots ×1) }{9!}=\frac{1}{12}.$$
The reason is that in the  events of our interest, only the type of objects matters, not their distinction. Hence, we can artificially assume that the objects of the same type are distinct (this assumption makes the outcomes of the experiment equally likely) and solve the problem using counting method, which gives the same result as the ones obtained from the conditional method, in which no assumption on distinction is required.
Note that without assuming that the objects are distinct you cannot generally use the counting method, as it may result in incorrect results. Though the counting method gives the same answer under both assumptions of distinct and same objects for the specific problem given in the OP, it gives different answers for the following slightly-altered problem:

We randomly pick 9 flowers from a box with 7 red and 11 yellow flowers. What is the probability of that 3 roses are chosen and appear next to each other.

Note that the above problem becomes the same as the problem in the OP if "7 red and 11 yellow flowers" is replaced by "3 red and 6 yellow flowers".
